# How can I have Akamai cache pages with domains that contain a hyphen/dash?

Tags: caching, dns, akamai

For some reason, Akamai does not cache pages with domains that contain hyphens/dashes in them. Has anyone else run into this problem? I can't seem to find anything online that answers this questions.

Answer (score 2):

Although caching at Akamai (especially caching an entire page) involves lot of other factors , by default Akamai should be able to handle domains with Hyphens/Dashes in them.  It would be great if you can give me a sample URL to a page you are trying to cache.

Answer (score 0):

Akamai supports this by default, and no additional changes are needed to support it.

Your problem lies elsewhere.